# Subset sum problem with condition on set composition

Tags: dynamic-programming, subset-sum

I have a problem where I am using dynamic programming for a subset sum problem. However here I need to include a condition on the set composition. For example, with a sum of 10 and an array : 3 5 5 7, we have two sets : 5 5 and 5 7

But let's consider that now I want to add a condition, which is to exclude some elements from my array like 7. In this case, the answer would be 5 5 only.

Any idea how to do this with dynamic programming?

Thanks!

EDIT :

For clarification, here each of the integers in my array (3 5 5 7) represent the size of a unique arrays.  For example :

- 3 => [11,12,13]
- 5 = > [1,2,3,5,6]
- 5 => [1,2,4,5,7]
- 7 => [1,2,3,4,8,9,10]

And I don't want to have any identical element in my one of my set, that is, [5,5] would not be solution because 1 belongs to both arrays of size 5 but [3,7] would be solution because no element of the array of size 3 is in the array of size 7.

I should have specified this detail, I'm sorry.

Comment: For any elements you don't want in your solution, why not just remove them from the original array before you do any other computation?

Comment: This won't help me because this problem comes from another sub-problem (see edit).